# Is it possible to install freeswitch in Debian 9.4?

Tags: web-services, nginx

I tried to install freeswitch in Debian 9.4 but i get some error. its say keys are invalid.

`root@.... :~# apt-get update 
Hit:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x jessie InRelease
Hit:2 http://128.30.2.26/debian testing InRelease

Get:3 http://files.freeswitch.org/repo/deb/freeswitch-1.6 jessie InRelease [4,628 B]
Ign:3 http://files.freeswitch.org/repo/deb/freeswitch-1.6 jessie InRelease
Get:4 http://files.freeswitch.org/repo/deb/freeswitch-1.6 jessie/main amd64 Packages [65.5 kB]
Fetched 70.1 kB in 2s (32.0 kB/s)

Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://files.freeswitch.org/repo/deb/freeswitch-1.6 jessie InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: 20B06EE621AB150D40F6079FD76EDC7725E010CF
W: The repository 'http://files.freeswitch.org/repo/deb/freeswitch-1.6 jessie InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can install it with a FreeSWITCH apt repository or install it from source as described on their confluence page:
https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Debian+9+Stretch